# Meteor remove duplicate property in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, object, meteor, handlebars.js, spacebars

I can't seem to figure out how to merge the two Video bullet points into one bullet point that contains the two drivers.

Collection Data

```
"drivers":[
    {"title":"Nvidia Video Driver","category":"Video","version":"331.82","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","filename":"nvidia.exe"},
    {"title":"Intel Video Driver","category":"Video","version":"10.4.4740","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ultricies.","filename":"intel.exe"},
    {"title":"Realtek Audio","category":"Audio","version":"1.25.21","description":"consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ultricies.","filename":"audio.exe"},
    {"title":"Storage controller","category":"chipset","version":"23.13.412","description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.","filename":"chip.exe"}
  ]
```

deviceDetails.helpers

```
Template.deviceDetails.helpers({
deviceDrivers:function(drivers) {

    var driverArray = drivers.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.category.toLowerCase() < b.category.toLowerCase()) return -1;
        if (a.category.toLowerCase() > b.category.toLowerCase()) return 1;
        return 0;
      });

    console.log(driverArray);
    return driverArray;
}
});
```

DeviceDetails.html

```
<ul>
    {{#each deviceDrivers device.drivers}}
        <li class="text-capitalize list-unstyled">{{category}}<ul>
          <li><a href="{{filename}}">{{title}} -> {{version}}</a><br>
            {{description}}
          </li></ul>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Result

```
- Audio
 - Realtek Audio -> 1.25.21
     - Consectetur Adipiscing Elit. Suspendisse Ultricies.
- Chipset
 - Storage Controller -> 23.13.412
     - Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Consectetur Adipiscing Elit.
- Video
    - Nvidia Video Driver -> 331.82
      - Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
- Video (!REMOVE! line)
    - Intel Video Driver -> 10.4.4740
      - Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Consectetur Adipiscing Elit. Suspendisse Ultricies.
```

Desired Result

```
- Audio
 - Realtek Audio -> 1.25.21
     - Consectetur Adipiscing Elit. Suspendisse Ultricies.
- Chipset
 - Storage Controller -> 23.13.412
     - Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Consectetur Adipiscing Elit.
- Video
    - Nvidia Video Driver -> 331.82
      - Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    - Intel Video Driver -> 10.4.4740
      - Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Consectetur Adipiscing Elit. Suspendisse Ultricies.
```

#### Update

I was able to get the desired result using [Julien Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33401832/921901).

```
deviceDrivers:function(drivers) {

    var driverArray = drivers.reduce(function(result, driver){
        var category = result.find(function(search){
            return search.category === driver.category;
        });
        if(category){
            category.drivers.push(driver);
        } else {
            result.push({
                category:driver.category,
                drivers: [driver]
            });
        }
            return result
        },[]).sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.category.toLowerCase() < b.category.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    if (a.category.toLowerCase() > b.category.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    return 0;
  });

    console.log(driverArray);
    return driverArray;
}
```

#### Update 2

[Christian Fritz Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33401849/921901) worked perfectly after his edit.

```
deviceDrivers:function(drivers) {
    var test = _.map(
    _.sortBy(
        _.groupBy(drivers, 'category'), function(value, key) {
            return key.toLowerCase();
        }), function(value, key) {
            return {category:value[0].category,drivers: value};
        });
    console.log(test);
    return test;
}
```

Comment: You can group the array elements by category upfront.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest pre-grouping:

JS:

```
Template.deviceDetails.helpers({
    deviceDrivers:function(drivers) {

        var driverGroups = 
            _.map(
                _.sortBy(
                    _.groupBy(drivers, 'category'), function(value, key) {
                        return key.toLower();
                    }), function(value, key) {
                        return {key: key, value: value};
                    });

        console.log(driverGroups);
        return driverGroups;
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    {{#each deviceDrivers device.drivers}}
        <li class="text-capitalize list-unstyled">{{key}}<ul>
          {{#with value}}
          <li><a href="{{filename}}">{{title}} -> {{version}}</a><br>
            {{description}}
          </li></ul>
          {{/with}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: When implementing the code provided I receive a couple of errors. The errors also show up in [Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/SREsRabeGorjKieMh/) Sorry if its a basic issue kinda new to javascript and meteor

Comment: sorry yeah there was a misplaced parenthesis. This is fixed now.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Also allowed me to group groups allowing for further breakdowns then before..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` :

```
    drivers.reduce(function(result, driver){
        var category = result.find(function(search){
            return search.category === driver.category;
        });
        if(category){
            category.drivers.push(driver);
        } else {
            result.push({
                category:driver.category,
                drivers: [driver]
            });
        }
        return result
    },[]);
```

I've learned that from [this tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMUiFMZr7vk), the guy is brilliant and very funny.

This will give you an array looking like:

```
[
  {
    "category": "Video",
    "drivers": [
      {
        "title": "Nvidia Video Driver",
        // ...
      },
      {
        "title": "Intel Video Driver",
        // ...          }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Audio",
    "drivers": [
      {
        "title": "Realtek Audio",
        // ...          }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "chipset",
    "drivers": [
      {
        "title": "Storage controller",
        // ...
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And then in your template, you should try something like:

```
<ul>
    {{#each deviceDrivers}}
        <li class="text-capitalize list-unstyled">{{category}}
         {{#each deviceDrivers}}
          <ul>
            <li><a href="{{filename}}">{{title}} -> {{version}}</a><br>
              {{description}}
            </li>
          </ul>
         {{/each}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: It's a good solution, but why reinvent the wheel? Meteor uses underscore by default and underscore already has `groupBy`.

Comment: I didn't know underscore was included in Meteor by default and I'm not familiar with all the helpers in the library. But sure, it looks better :)